# Including Content-Security-Policy in React

Tags: html, reactjs, meta, content-security-policy

I want to include Content-Security-Policy to my React website. This is what I added to index.html in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none';
      script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
      https://www.google-analytics.com/
      https://maps.googleapis.com/
      https://developers.google.com/;
      img-src 'self'
      https://www.google-analytics.com
      https://maps.googleapis.com/
      https://maps.gstatic.com/
      https://developers.google.com/ data:;
      style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline';
      font-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com data:;
      frame-src 'self' https://www.slideshare.net;
      upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content;
      connect-src 'self'">
```

I used this website- https://www.htbridge.com/websec/ to check if my website is secured and I still got 'F'. The problem is that I have many misconfiguration such that: X-FRAME-OPTIONS, X-XSS-PROTECTION, X-CONTENT-TYPE-OPTIONS and also CONTENT-SECURITY-POLICY. Am I doing something wrong or should I add more 'settings' to make it secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content-Security-Policy is just one of the security measures to avoid some sort of attacks, and this can be used within the React index.html.

However, the other methods you mentioned (X-Frame-Options, X-XSS-Protection, X-Content-Type-Options, etc) are essentially set in the server side when receiving http(s) requests.

For instance, if the server hosting your React website is Apache, then you can add these lines in the '**.htaccess**' file:

```
# Set Strict-Transport-Security
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS

# Set X-Frame-Options (Protect against page-framing and click-jacking)
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

# Set X-Content-Type-Options (Protect against content-sniffing)
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

# Set X-XSS-Protection (Protect against XSS attacks)
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

# Set Referrer-Policy
Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
```